# How to replace character in row of dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, replace

I open raw data using pandas

```
df=pd.read_cvs(file)
```

Here's part of my dataframe look like:

```
37280  7092|156|Laboratory Data|A648C751-A4DD-4CZ2-85                               
47981  7092|156|Laboratory Data|Z22CD01C-8Z4B-4ZCB-8B                               
57982  7092|156|Laboratory Data|C12CE01C-8F4B-4CZB-8B
```

I'd like to replace all pipe(`'|'`) into tab (`'\t'`)
So I tried :

```
df.replace('|','\t')
```

But it never works. How could I do this?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `replace` method on data frame by default is meant to replace values exactly match the string provided; You need to specify `regex=True` to replace patterns, and since `|` is a special character in regex, an escape is needed here:

```
df1 = df.replace("\|", "\t", regex=True)
df1
#       0                                                   1
#0  37280   7092\t156\tLaboratory Data\tA648C751-A4DD-4CZ2-85
#1  47981   7092\t156\tLaboratory Data\tZ22CD01C-8Z4B-4ZCB-8B
#2  57982   7092\t156\tLaboratory Data\tC12CE01C-8F4B-4CZB-8B
```

If we print the cell, the tab are printed as expected:

```
print(df1[1].iat[0])
# 7092  156 Laboratory Data A648C751-A4DD-4CZ2-85
```

Comment: Yes it works! Problem comes from missing escape for the special regex. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helps !

Answer (score 1):

Just need to set the variable to itself:
`df = df.replace('|', '\t')`